# call a method return type without invoke

Tags: java

i want to create a code where i can call listeners from any class.
Example there is a class called
MyCustomClass.java which contains this method:

```
    public ListenerReturn canCreatureAttack(final CanCreatureAttack canCreatureAttack)
    {
        if (canCreatureAttack.getAttacker().isSuperPlayer))
        {
           return new listenerReturn(true);
        }
        
        return false;
    }
```

Now in the same class in initialization constructor i store in a global ListenerContainer static class the current object and the method and the parameter `CanCreatureAttack(actor, target)`

Later in some other code i can do a check using

final ListenerReturn return = ListenerContainer.executeListener("myClassName", new CanCreatureAttack(actor, target));

and this will execute the method in that class without invoke or reflection like Consumer and return the result ListenerReturn.

But how i can do this i'm confused.

Comment: create an object of the class and call non static method.

Comment: Isnt there any way like Consumer which u can return the result of it? I don't want make a new object of that class, we speak for a game here and it might be a player's attack and i dont want to create 3000 objects per 1 second.

Comment: `execute the method in that class without invoke` ehhh, how is that supposed to work? You need to execute the method to get the result, unless you already know the result, in which case you wouldn't need to execute anything. For your example, a static method would definitely suffice. `public static boolean canCreatureAttack(params){do your check and return result}`

Comment: How about Supplier? :/